# Cloudinary give me { message: 'Empty file', http_code: 400 } after separate module

Tags: node.js, express, multer, cloudinary

My code work fine upload resized Image to cloudinary with this, Saved resized Image at local, up to cloudinary and remove image

```
    const compressedResult = await sharp(req.file.buffer)
     .resize(1366, 768).toFormat("jpeg")
     .jpeg({
      quality: 90,
      chromaSubsampling: '4:4:4'
      })
     .toFile('./public/compressed/' + req.file.originalname)
     const file = item(req.file)
     const uploadResult = await cloudinary.uploader.upload('./public/compressed/' + req.file.originalname)
     fs.unlinkSync('./public/compressed/' + req.file.originalname)
```

But when i separate the Sharp module

```
let item = (req) => {
    sharp(req.buffer).resize(848, 480).toFormat("jpeg")
      .jpeg({
        quality: 90,
        chromaSubsampling: '4:4:4'
      })
      .toFile('./public/compressed/' + req.originalname)
}
```

and controller

```
item(req.file)
const uploadResult = await cloudinary.uploader.upload('./public/compressed/' + req.file.originalname)
console.log(req.file, ' FILE ');
fs.unlinkSync('./public/compressed/' + req.file.originalname)
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LE11.png)
[Log Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI3wp.png)

Comment: Are you sure the file exists on disk at the time the Cloudinary SDK tries to open it and send it in the API call? That's the most likely reason for such an error

You may also be able to stop using Sharp completely and use Cloudinary's functionality to perform the same operation before the file is saved into your account: Scaling to 1366*768, conversion to JPEG, quality 90 and Chroma subsampling of 4:4:4 can be done directly when uploading via an [incoming transformation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#incoming_transformations)

Comment: (or when delivering the image by transforming it on-the-fly: https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/q_90:444,f_jpg,w_1366,h_768,c_scale/sample.jpg )

Comment: it's appear in my local storage already bro, but it's error when trying to upload it :( 
https://imgur.com/a/j0MEm8z